# How to add momentum to camera movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the camera follow the player movement

but the problem is when the condition that make the camera follow the player is not met it immediately stops which does not looks realistic

i want it to move a little further after the condition is evaluated to false

sorry that my English is not good
but here's the code to clarify things up

```cs
void Update()
    {
        if(player.position.x - transform.position.x >= 3 && transform.position.x <= 1.35)
        {
            transform.Translate(3.5f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (player.position.x - transform.position.x <= -3  && transform.position.x >= -1.35)
        {
            transform.Translate(-3.5f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want it to overshoot a bit?

Comment: what i want is like inertia

Comment: Simple solution : start a coroutine when it's false, running for X time and simulating this effect. More complex : You could "queue" the camera translation, and delaying the translation